# Any way to enforce naming standards in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, naming-conventions

I am aware of http://omnidroid.googlecode.com/svn/tools/Eclipse_Formatter-ITP_Conventions.xml that can be imported into my Android projects Formatter , but it doesn't enforce naming convention standards. I know there are many standards available per project but I'd rather if there were rules set to ensure it. Is there another XML file I can import into my formatter to ensure such? Something like the Resource Style Rules at the end of the page at https://github.com/iamshanedoyle/Android-CodingConvention would be great to have, but I don't really know how to code this into the XML file?

Comment: Convention cant be enforced they have to be followed by developers only. If they are not doing so they are not true java developers.

Comment: I am aware that the developers should know of the convention - but I'd rather have a suggestion show up on the IDE saying something like "Consider renaming this to '' " . I was just wondering if that was possible

Comment: Then you have to search for some king of Ide Plugins which can help you

Answer (score 0):

Formatter can only help you to maintain formatting.

Also check the Code Style part of the project configuration, like variable prefixes and suffixes; those help to use Content Assist for example with getters: if you have a member named `m_x` and prefix is set to `m_` you get a suggestion for `getX()/setX(T)` upon pressing `Ctrl+Space`; without it, you'd get a funny getM_x() suggestion.

The best solution to your problem may be setting up PMD/Checkstyle for your project and failing build in CI if invalid code is submitted.

I sometimes set all these up together, so Formatter/Code Style helps to write code which adheres to PMD/Checkstyle rules. Also I set up Save Actions in Eclipse so that I don't have to press `Ctrl+Shift+F` and `Ctrl+Shift+O`, etc. repeatedly, just a simple `Ctrl+S` does the work.